# Opening a modal (overlay) window in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, hyperlink, target

I need to open up a modal (overlay) window in Wordpress from the main menu. The contents will be another page.

E.g. abc.com has a link on the menu bar that when clicked will open up an overlay box. The content of this overlay box will be xyz.com/target-content.

Is this possible? Perhaps there's a plugin that allows this?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved with Thickbox :o)

Unfortunately, there's an iFrame on the destination page that IE refuses to open. I don't suppose anyone knows how to bypass that one?